# How to pass multiple user ids to the controller in a Laravel policy file

Tags: php, laravel

In my `Product` `Policy` file I have the following:

```
public function change_customer_pricing(User $user) {
    return $user->id == 2;
}
```

How do I return more than one `user ID` to the `Controller`?

My controller:

```
public function change_customer_pricing($ProdID) {
    $user = Auth::user();
            
    //dd($user->can('change_customer_pricing', Product::class));
        
    if (!$user->can('change_customer_pricing', Product::class)) 
    return redirect()->route('home')->with('status', 'You are not Authorized to access')->with('code', 'red');
...
```

Comment: You don't. Policies generally return a truthy or `boolean` response. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you want the policy to allow another user besides the user with id = 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function change_customer_pricing(User $user){
    
    return in_array($user->UserID,[2,12,14]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to determine if a `User` has authorisation to perform an action on a `Product`, you need a relationship between the `User` and `Product` and then check the relationship.

Say you have a `user_id` field on your `Product` which holds the `id` of the `User` that created that `Product` for example and only that `User` is allowed to update or delete the `Product`. You would want to check the `id` of the authenticated `User` matches the `user_id` of the `Product`.

```
public function change_customer_pricin(User $user, Product $product)
{
    return $user->id === $product->user_id;
}
```

Then you can use any of the baked in authorisation functions with Laravel. As you're wanthing to check if a `User` is authorised from a controller, you can do:

```
public function change_customer_pricing($ProdID)
{
    $product = Product::find($ProdId);

    $this->authorize('change_product_pricing', $product);
}
```

As a side note, you might want to consider using [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding) in your controller.

**Update**

As your `Product` doesn't have a relationship to a `User` and you're looking to authorise multiple `Users`, you could check `id` of the currently authenticated `User` against an array:

```
public function change_customer_pricin(User $user)
{
    return in_array($user->id, [1, 2, 3, 4];
}
```

This is the quickest and simplest solution. However, it is not very maintainable as you'd have to add/remove as requirements changed.

A better solution would be to use roles and permissions to determine authorisation. You define permissions which are used scope access then you can associate (assign) permissions directly to a `User` or to a `Role` (and the a `Role` to a `User`). When an action is performed, you check if a `User` has the required `Role` or `Permission`.

There are a few packages available which provide such functionalty, a very popular option is [Spatie Permission](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/introduction) and another popular choice is [Laratrust](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/).

Comment: Thanks for the response, there is no userid field on the product. I am just looking to prevent certain users by userid from being able to access certain actions in the controller like the change_customer_pricing function.

Comment: @user2197774 I have added an update to my answer based on your comment.